# SAS program, How to do the calculation based on two tables without IML

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I've been struggling with some matrix calculation in sas. 
I have two tables, which both contain Longitude and Latitude information

Tasks table

[image]

Engineers table:

[image]

My output goal is the distance between tasks and engineers

Distances:

[image]

Due to the additional cost for SAS/IML, I don't have it on premises. Does someone have any experience how to do that?

P.S. The code in R is easy as follows

```
   distances <- matrix(nrow = NROW(tasks), ncol = NROW(cses))
   for (i in 1:NROW(tasks)){
     for(j in 1:NROW(cses)){
       distances[i,j] <- distm (c(tasks$CUST_LNG_X[i], tasks$CUST_LAT_Y[i]), c(cses$LNG_X[j], cses$LAT_Y[j]), fun = distHaversine)

     }
   }
```

Comment: Please do not post images in the future, include your data like the users below did as a data step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something but a cross join should also work fine with the GEODIST function and then a transpose to make it wide. It doesn't matter how many points are in each file, though I suppose if it got big enough SQL may error out due to memory.

```
proc sql;
create table want as
select task_id as col1, id as col2, geodist(a.x, a.y, b.x, b.y) as distance
from tasks as a , engineers as b;
quit;

proc transpose data=want out=want_wide ;
by col1;
id col2;
var distance;
run;
```

Comment: This. It was late when I answered and as soon as I hit the bed I realized it was much (much) simpler than that.

Answer (score 1):

Well there is the [GEODIST](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a003113162.htm) function which does just that.

Assuming the tables called `tasks` and `engineers` with the structure you present in your post (for future reference, we rather have those as text instead of images), you can obtain the third table with the following:

```
proc sql;
create table engineers_2 as
select compress(id||'_y') as id
      ,geo_y as geo
from engineers
union
select compress(id||'_x') as id
      ,geo_x as geo
from engineers
order by id
;
quit;

proc transpose data=engineers_2 out=t_engineers(drop=_name_);
var geo;
id id;
run;

proc sql;
create table want as
select *
from tasks
    ,t_engineers
;
quit;
```

This will give you a table that will have the following columns

```
task_id geo_y geo_x E_1_x E_1_y E_2_x E_2_y E_3_x E_3_y
```

where `geo_y` and `geo_x` are the coordinates of the task `task_id` and `E_n_x` and `E_n_y` are the coordinates of engineer `n`.

It is then just a matter of processing the dataset line by line, feeding the variables in the `geodist` function.

Comment: HI!

I know the GEODIST. My main problem is the dynamic column, which is generated from the engineers table. How am I gonna get that format.

Comment: Edited my answer

Comment: both work, I will accept Reeza's answer. Big thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This is very similar to user2877959.

```
data tasks;
input Task_ID $ Y X;
datalines;
T_1 41.65 -74.08
T_2 32.48 -86.46
;
run;

%let n=2; /*This is the number of engineer points*/

data engineers;
input ID $ Y X;
datalines;
E_1 40.92 -81.31
E_2 39.98 -74.87
;
run;
```

I differ by putting creating the `X_` and `Y_` are suffixes.  This will make things easier.  I'm doing this in a data step and then transposing.  Using SQL works too.

```
data engineers;
set engineers;
X_NAME = catt("X_",id);
Y_NAME = catt("Y_",id);
run;

proc transpose data=engineers(keep=x_name x) out=e_x;
id x_name;
run;

proc transpose data=engineers(keep=y_name y) out=e_y;
id y_name;
run;

/*This puts the engineer data into 1 record in a single table*/
data engineers;
merge e_y e_x;
drop _name_;
run;

proc sql noprint;
create table want as
select a.*,
       b.*
    from tasks a,
         engineers b;
quit;
```

The last step is to calculate the distances.  We can use DATA STEP arrays to help with the processing.

```
data want;
set want;
array E_[&n];
array X_E_[&n];
array Y_E_[&n];

do i=1 to &n;
    E_[i] = geodist(x,y,x_e_[i],y_e_[i]);
end;

drop X: Y: i;
run;
```